# Why I can't see deleted files in the git commit history?

Tags: git, git-commit

Half-way through a project development I deleted some files from my repo.

I checked both commit history both locally and on GitHub, and I can't see these files in any of the commits. I wonder how is this possible that I can't see them in ANY of the previous commits. I'm sure I had them in this project because these were `.png` files used in my `.md` files, so I still see their paths in my `.md` files. For example: `![](./images/postgresql/numeric_data_types.png)`.

I tried to search for these files and their paths with the followings commands:

`git log --all --full-history -- './images/postgresql/numeric_data_types.png'`

`git log --all --full-history -- '**/numeric_data_types.png'`

`git log --diff-filter=D --summary`

`git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- ./images/postgresql/`

None of these commands return any trace of the files like they've never been in the repo.

I also inspected commit history manually through GitHub website. Also no trace.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

My git config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user/repo_name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

Comment: Did you check they're not ignored? (and if so, untracked)

Comment: Try taking a look at your `.gitignore` file and the content of `.git/config/exclude`. Maybe the images were actually never under version control and you just didn’t notice because Git never told you?

Comment: They are not mentioned in `.gitignore` file of HEAD repo. In regards to your suggestion that the images were never under version control. This seems very unlikely to me because I recall seeing them online (I checked my .md files to see if they are displaying online on GitHub).

Comment: @Boldewyn I added insides of my git config file to the question. There is no `exclude` section.

Comment: Ah, sorry! The file is named `.git/info/exclude`. It’s like a local `.gitignore` that won’t be committed to the repo.

Comment: Other suggestions: (1) check branches (local and remote), maybe something is hidden there. (2) check the output of `git reflog` whether there is something strange going on, like rebases that you don’t recall.

Comment: @Boldewyn I checked the `exclude` file. There is nothing there but comments. I also checked the reflogs. I checked out to a specific commit, one I'm sure included the files I'm looking for. This commit was made BEFORE the day I deleted the files and therefore should include these files. I only have main branch at the moment. I doubt this is of any help, but these were image files in `./images` folder.

Comment: Another silly idea: Do you use more than one computer to work with the repo? There could be a repo on computer A and a repo on computer B. Theoretically, if you added the images on A and pushed to Github, then continued working on B, pushed again to Github (w/o pulling first, and using the `--force` cli parameter) the images would be gone without a trace. Apart from that I’m basically out of ideas what could have happened.

Comment: @Boldewyn I indeed used two machines for this repo. I checked the reflogs on the second machine and didn't find `--force` command there. I could have done it on a different branch thought. I also managed to restore another branch on github, but didn't find the files there neither. Maybe I have messed up on the `.gitignore` file at some stage (maybe it was a very early stage, but I'm pretty sure I saw this files working with the corresponding .md files). So I don't know. Side question: should I include `.gitignore` inside the `.gitignore` file? In other words, should I push this file to remote?

Comment: Yes, usually you should commit `.gitignore` to the repo. The `.gitignore` should contain all files that will always need to be excluded in every cloned repo, e.g. build targets, helper files, editor tmp files, ... If you want to ignore a file on one specific machine, use `.git/info/exclude` for this. That file cannot be committed to the repo.